# Can nightmarejs get detected as a bot?

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I just came across nightmarejs, prior to it I was using cefsharp in c# which is pretty good but my c# knowledge is low so i was looking for a nodejs framework that automates chromium.
I did search stackoverflow and on google but did not find a clear answer
To explain my bot will do:

- Visit site
- Login
- Do stuff

I will be using local storage and no proxy support needed so I don't have to worry about webrtc etc.
The bot needs to not leak stuff like selenium or librarues like that.

If nightmare is not the tool to go can you recommend me something else?

thanks

Comment: @mihai thanks for ediding, wrote if fast by phone
anyway do you have anything to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nightmare uses [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) under the hood, which in turn uses [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home). So it's Chromium that your website will detect when inspecting [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.42 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chromium/25.0.1349.2 Chrome/25.0.1349.2 Safari/537.42
```

You can also [manually set user agent](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#useragentuseragent) in Nightmare:

```
.useragent(useragent)
```

So I would say no, a typical website would not be able to detect Nightmare using basic checks. However some apps/website use behavior analysis to detect bots/scripts, so you won't be immune to that.

Comment: clearly understand, as long as it does not leak itself that's super for me.
For example selenium leaks javascript strings and needs recompiling from source to fix, yet i dont feel safe to use it for such project and that's why i asked before i start.
Thanks for the help